# Sql query within an inner join

Tags: mysql

i have this mysql statement :

```
SELECT ca.*, MAX(ca.id), v.*,a.submit_dt from callback_holding ca 
inner join valuations v on v.Ref = ca.ref
inner join answer a on a.title = ca.ref
where v.Consultant = '$user' and ca.isholding = 2 
GROUP BY ca.ref DESC order by ca.reccomendeddate asc
```

But the problem is if there is not an entry in "answer" then it doesn't show up in the list. What is the correct way to bring back everything and just "null" if there is nothing in the "answer" table?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you want a `left outer join` -- a little more complicated than inner joins, I'd recommend reading about them somewhere online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has several problems.  First, you are grouping by the `ref` column from the `callback_holding` table, but are selecting non aggregate columns not only from this table, but from other tables.  To get around this, you should do the aggregation to find maximum IDs in `callback_holding` in a subquery, and then join it to the other tables.

Next, you mentioned that if no answer be found, you get back no records.  This is the nature of an `INNER JOIN`, but if you switch the join to `answer` to use a `LEFT JOIN`, then no records up to that point in the query will be lost.  Note that I used `COALESCE(a.submit_dt, 'NA')` to display `NA` in the event that this column from the answer table be `NULL`.  If this column be `datetime`, then you should use a suitable default value, e.g. `NOW()`.

```
SELECT ca.*,
       v.*,
       COALESCE(a.submit_dt, 'NA') AS submit_dt,   -- display 'NA' if no answer
       t.max_id
FROM callback_holding ca
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ref, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM callback_holding
    GROUP BY ref
) t
    ON t.ref = ca.ref AND
       t.max_id = ca.id
INNER JOIN valuations v
    ON v.Ref = ca.ref
LEFT JOIN answer a
    ON a.title = ca.ref
WHERE v.Consultant = '$user' AND
      ca.isholding = 2
ORDER BY ca.reccomendeddate
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer. I tried to run that query and got the below error.

Comment: 4 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "t" at position 84)
Unexpected token. (near "t" at position 84)
Unexpected token. (near "." at position 85)
Unexpected token. (near "max_id" at position 86)

Comment: @GazSmith Sorry, there was a comma missing in the `SELECT` clause.  Please try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
SELECT ca.*, MAX(ca.id), v.*,a.submit_dt from callback_holding ca 
INNER join valuations v on v.Ref = ca.ref
LEFT join answer a on a.title = ca.ref
WHERE v.Consultant = '$user' and ca.isholding = 2 
GROUP BY ca.ref DESC order by ca.reccomendeddate asc
```